# Tombstoning Canvas Visibility Property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have small problem with retrieving the state of a canvas' visibility property. When I retrieve the page state, the canvas is always visible even if it was collapsed when it was tombstoned. I tried a bunch of if else and switch statements but with no luck. How do I fix this bug? Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to help!

Here's the code:

```
    private const string coachPivotKey = "CoachPivotKey";
    private const string isVisibleKey = "IsVisibleKey";

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SaveState(coachPivotKey, coachPivot.SelectedIndex);
        this.SaveState(isVisibleKey, canvasNotes.Visibility);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        coachPivot.SelectedItem = coachPivot.Items[this.LoadState<int>(coachPivotKey)];
        canvasNotes.Visibility = this.LoadState<Visibility>(isVisibleKey);

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

The LoadState() and SaveState() methods are in a different class. These I got from a video I watched on tombstoning:

```
public static void SaveState(this PhoneApplicationPage phoneApplicationPage, string key, object value)
    {
        if (phoneApplicationPage.State.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            phoneApplicationPage.State.Remove(key);
        }

        phoneApplicationPage.State.Add(key, value);
    }

public static T LoadState<T>(this PhoneApplicationPage phoneApplicationPage, string key)
    {
        if (phoneApplicationPage.State.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (T)phoneApplicationPage.State[key];
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: When you debug through, is the value for the Visibility inside the State dictionary?

Comment: Yes the both Visible and Collapsed values go to the SaveState() dictionary

Comment: But can you see them inside LoadState (i.e. were they actually stored properly)

Comment: no only isVisible key is registering

Comment: confused what you mean there. Are the two values you want being saved, but not having any effect, or are they not being saved?

Comment: when I debug through the canvas' LoadState() method, it only shows me the isVisible key value and not the visibility property values.

Comment: Try saving the Visibility as a bool rather than Visibility.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: Visibility has two states. :) this.SaveState(isVisibleKey,coachNotes.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;  canvasNotes.Visibility = this.LoadState<bool>(isVisibleKey) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

Comment: Yes that did it! Thank you so very much for helping me out AGAIN! :D You're my savior! :D :D

Comment: cool, odd that it can't save enumeration types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving a `System.Windows.Visibility`, save a `bool` indicating whether the control is visible.

```
this.SaveState(isVisibleKey,coachNotes.Visibility == Visibility.Visible); 


canvasNotes.Visibility = this.LoadState<bool>(isVisibleKey) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
```